# Socialauth android get profile picture from google

Tags: android, oauth, openid, socialauth

I'm using this library https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ to login into my application using google account. So far so good. I can get user name, email but get user profile picture. I think, that library uses OpenId + Oauth to login and after call:

```
profile.getProfileImageURL()
```

i get null.

I can get token and secret (OpenId ?) by calling:

```
socialAuthAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant()
For example:
token key : 1/J0_R-D03mykbqHnnNrVV1lk9FH2j996G05O2WVcHTrQ
token secret : vnh25rzUBVJKjHNpT_USeyjK
```

but i can't use this to retrieve user profile url by using link: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo

Can you give me any tips, how to use what i get from this library to get also picture url ?

My oauth_consumer.properties:

```
www.google.com.consumer_key = xxxxx.com
www.google.com.consumer_secret = xxxxxxxxxx
www.google.com.custom_permissions = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delayed response. We monitor socialauth questions on our Google project regularly.

The problem is that Google OpenId + OAuth api does not give image URL. We are in process of retrofitting the Google provider with Google+, so this will be available in the next minor release - star our Google project socialauth for updates.